# Concatenating Content between Heredoc Tags

Tags: php, html, tcpdf, heredoc

I am converting some formatted html text to a PDF file, and in doing so, I must place a table in the document. In order to put the table into the PDF correctly, I must use heredoc tags instead of regulars quotations (Came to this conclusion through some experimentation). What I am wondering is whether I can take some content from a POST call and place it between the heredoc tags a la:

```
$table = $_POST['table'];
$html = <<<EOD . '$table' . EOD;
```

Or, something of the like. I haven't come across a solution, and was wondering if this was even possible. I have tried passing the table variable directly to the method, but it is a fruitless effort. It does work if passed with the heredoc tags, however.

Comment: Well that heredoc syntax is broken for a start, start tag must be followed by end of line, end must be at start of own line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use an [Encapsulated Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for this purpose. Example #5 on that page. It allows you to place the heredoc in quotes and use curly braces to utilize your variables.

**PHP Example**

```
$hey = 'Test 1 2 3';

$html = <<<"TEST"
Test me: {$hey}
TEST;

echo $html;
```

**Returns**

```
Test me: Test 1 2 3
```

Comment: I have tried this, and I guess the problem has to do with the PDF rendering engine of TCPDF because this outputs an unformatted table. Thanks

Comment: That's unfortunate. Good Luck.

Comment: remove the double quote in your "TEST"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like the PHP documentation says:

```
$name = 'Davis';

echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $_POST['table'].
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]} too!
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

You have to make sure that your text is **between** your starting and ending line.